# @ManyToOne mapping between entities without a foreign key constraint. javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I Have an Entity class Certificate which has an Entity class CertificateProfile.

```
public class Certificate {
    @Id
    private String certId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="certificateProfileId", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "none"))
    private CertificateProfile certificateProfile;
}

public class CertificateProfile {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String certificateProfileName;
...
}
```

I'm working with a legacy database. So there is no foreign key constraint even though the certificateProfileId column holds the id of the certificateProfile.
When i try to get the certificate list via `CertificateDataRepository.findAll()`. I get `javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find CertificateProfile with id 0` 
I tried to set the fetchType to Lazy but I get this error:

```
could not initialize proxy [CertificateProfileData#1508963102] - no Session
```

Answer (score 3):

It happens in some legacy schema which do not use NULL to indicate the absent of many-to-one entities in the relationship column  but instead use some magic value (which I guess in your case this magic value is 0).

By default, Hibernate throws `EntityNotFoundException` if the many-to-one entities does not exist. You can use Hibernate feature `@NotFound` to tell Hibernate to ignore this exception and simply assign null to the `many-to-one` entities reference.

```java
    @ManyToOne
    @NotFound ( action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE )
    @JoinColumn(name="certificateProfileId", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "none"))
    private CertificateProfile certificateProfile;
```

Comment: Thank for your response. I verified manually that every certificateProfileId exists in the table certificateProfile. so it is not absent.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no relation(constraint) between 2 entities at the database level, you do not have to keep the mapping in the class. Remove these 2 lines:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="certificateProfileId", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "none"))
```

and write as follows:

```
@Column(name="cert_profile_id")
private Long certificateProfileId;
```